# css animation not working in chrome (delay not respected on webkit mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I'm trying to animate a div with a translate3D, it's working perfectly everywhere except on webkit-mobile where the property is well interpreted but the div goes directly to the endpoint without any delay.

I tried to use the webkit transition property without any difference and the debugger is telling me that everything should work.

Please tell me you know how to solve this

**JS**

```
function setTransform(x, y, deg, duration) {
    current.style.transform = `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0) rotate(${deg}deg)`
    likeText.style.opacity = Math.abs((x / innerWidth * 2.1))
    likeText.className = `is-like ${x > 0 ? 'like' : 'nope'}`
    if (duration) {
      current.style.transition = `transform ${duration}ms`
      current.style.webkitTransition = `transform ${duration}ms`
      // debugger;
    }
}
```

**CSS** of the "current" element

```
.card {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    touch-action: none;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

EDIT :
x,y,deg are working perfectly and duration is around/should be around 1000ms